# Date filtered for collection on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is it possible to select from a collection of images for example of 30 years and ask only the image of July for each year? The below only include July images for a single year.

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point([0, 10])
Map.addLayer(aoi)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filterDate('2020-07-01', '2020-08-01')
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: You can filter your collection based on day of the year with `ee.Filter.calendarRange(183, 213, 'day_of_year')`. Because of leap years, you don't get exact calendar month, but hopefully close enough for your use-case. 

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9e2fe3a1785ce3a676a245154c58375a

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel suggests, use `ee.Filter.calendarRange()` for 30 years sequence and for July filtering. You can stack `.filter()` functions:

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point([0, 10])
Map.addLayer(aoi)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1990,2020,'year'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7,7,'month'));
```

A 30 years sequence isn't possible to obtain from S2 since it was launched in 2015